# Making a island large leetcode - spotting mistake Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am working on LeetCode problem [827. Making A Large Island](https://leetcode.com/problems/making-a-large-island/):

> You are given an `n x n` binary matrix `grid`. You are allowed to change **at most** one `0` to be `1`.
>
> Return *the size of the largest **island** in grid after applying this operation.*
>
> An **island** is a 4-directionally connected group of `1`s.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input:** `grid = [[1,0],[0,1]]`
> **Output:** `3`
> **Explanation:** Change one 0 to 1 and connect two 1s, then we get an island with area = 3.

My solution fails for the following test case:

```
[[1,1,0],[0,0,0], [1,1,0]]
```

The output of my code is 3, but 5 is expected.

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public int largestIsland(int[][] grid) {
        int n=grid.length;
        int max=0;
        boolean hasZero=false;
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[n][n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(grid[i][j]==0){
                    grid[i][j]=1;
                    max=Math.max(max,area(grid,n,i,j,visited));  
                    grid[i][j]=0;
                   // visited[i][j]=false;
                    hasZero=true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return hasZero?max:n*n;
    }
    
    private int area(int[][] grid, int n, int i, int j, boolean[][] visited){
        if(i<0 || i>n-1 || j>n-1 || j<0 || grid[i][j]==0 || visited[i][j])
            return 0;
        
        visited[i][j]=true;
        int a1 =  area(grid,n,i+1,j,visited);
        int a2 =  area(grid,n,i,j+1,visited);
        int a3 = area(grid,n,i-1,j,visited);
        int a4 =  area(grid,n,i,j-1,visited);
            
        return 1+a1+a2+a3+a4;
    }
}
```

This solution is O(N^4) and I know other, more efficient working solutions, but I'm not able to spot what's wrong with my attempt.

Could someone spot what is wrong?

Comment: I updated your question to include the problem description (as essential info should not be behind a link), and made explicit what the expected output is for the failing test case. With these elements your question could be considered for reopening (and potential upvoting).

Comment: Note that this problem can be solved in essentially linear time with a disjoint set data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after you have marked an island as visited, it can no longer play a role in a better connection.

For instance, your failing test case:

```
[[1, 1, ],[0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 0]]
```

...can be depicted as:

```
 1 1 0
 0 0 0
 1 1 0
```

Your code will first try this (changing the value in brackets):

```
 1 1(1)
 0 0 0
 1 1 0
```

... and mark those as visited (I'll mark those with "v"):

```
 v v v
 0 0 0
 1 1 0
```

...and so it finds 3 for `max`.

Then it will continue with finding the following:

```
 v v v
(1)0 0
 1 1 0
```

This will lead to a value of 3, which does not improve the previous value for `max`. But this is wrong, because it really connects with another island that you had marked visited. It should have found this:

```
 1 1 0
(1)0 0
 1 1 0
```

... which is 5.

As you already found working algorithms, I suppose this answers your question.